# Issue while installing app in galaxy tab

Tags: android, galaxy

I have samsung galaxy tab android 2.2.1. Previously I was able to install the app from my pc through cable but suddenly, I am not able to install the app from my pc and also I didn't get the USB icon when connected to my pc but tab is getting charged. I dont know what the problem is. Is there any settings I need to change.

Here is my current settings.

```
I have selected Settings->Application->Development->USB debugging.
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.How to install kies....

Comment: Download it from samsung's website http://www.samsung.com/pk/support/usefulsoftware/KIES/JSP

Answer (score 0):

Check your device manager , if you have a yellow mark next to your device name you can update your drivers manually with Samsung Adb Interface driver or installing Samsung Kies

Answer (score 0):

To get your Samsung device sync with your PC use Samsung Kies. you can download it from here:

http://www.samsung.com/pk/support/usefulsoftware/KIES/JSP

Translate the page if it is not in English. Install it and you'll be able to play with your device..:-)

Comment: I have installed samsung kies in my pc and then also device is not connected.Before installing kies My device name is not shown in Device Manager.Now also i didnt see the device name there...

Comment: Check that you have USB Debugging enabled in device settings?

Comment: Are you on a cyanogen mod rom? If you are then settings>storage>menu button top right>usb computer connection>MTP

Comment: I think its not bcoz,there is only Sdcard and device storage in my settings and i didnt find usb computer connection in that...